# Password encryption type

Tags: mysql, encryption, password

I would like to confirm if MySQL uses SHA1 for 'PASSSWORD' hashing and why test below doesn't work:

```
mysql> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='test';
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host       | password                                  |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
| test | localhost  | *2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19 |
+------+------------+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> \q
Bye
[root@test ~]# echo -n "password" | sha1sum | awk '{print toupper($1)}'
5BAA61E4C9B93F3F0682250B6CF8331B7EE68FD8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL documentation [Encryption and Compression Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) page has various functions that can be used for hashing passwords. It also clearly states that:

> Note
>
> The `PASSWORD()` function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should not use it in your own applications. For that purpose, consider `MD5()` or `SHA2()` instead. Also see RFC 2195, section 2 (Challenge-Response Authentication Mechanism (CRAM)), for more information about handling passwords and authentication securely in your applications.

As for the other question, you can [test at SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/16690) that `PASSWORD()` (at least in versions 5.1, 5.5 and 5.6 that we can test at SQL-Fiddle) is implemented as applying `SHA1()` **twice** on the provided string:

```
SELECT 
  SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password'))),
  PASSWORD('password');
```

Thanks should go to Rene Cannao who has digged into the source code and provided the answer in the blog post: [PalominoDB.com : Hashing Algorithm in MySQL PASSWORD()](http://palominodb.com/blog/2011/12/04/hashing-algorithm-mysql-password)

There is also this, older answer on StackOverflow which is relevant: [Simulating MySql's password() encryption using .NET or MS SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868482/simulating-mysqls-password-encryption-using-net-or-ms-sql)

If you want to confim with Linux CLI, just tested at Ubuntu:

```
ypercube@Zeus:~$    echo -n "password" | sha1sum |
      perl -ne 's/([0-9a-f]{2})/print chr hex $1/gie' | sha1sum
2470c0c06dee42fd1618bb99005adca2ec9d1e19  -
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know why there is different has from CLI?

Comment: What difference are you referring to?

Comment: The hash that I've created via CLI (sha1sum) is different from the one from MySQL.

Comment: did you try applying `sha1sum` twice?

Answer (score 0):

1. it isn't encryption, it's hashing, which is different.
2. MD5 and SHA-1 are both broken and vulnerable and you should not use them for password hashing. Use BCrypt.

[MD5 considered harmful](http://www.win.tue.nl/hashclash/rogue-ca/)

[SHA-1 Broken](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html)

Comment: The relevant security.stackexchnage link regarding point 2 is [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623)